# how to start drillbit distributed and in single node with Windows?

Tags: apache, hadoop, cygwin, apache-zookeeper, apache-drill

I want to start drillbit sevrer in Distributed mode in Windows but didn't work,

I started ZooKeeper and works fine with " zkServer.cmd ", and started drill with cygwin command like this : " sh drillbit.sh start " but the server don't start and give this error in drillbit.out log file :

```
C:\Drill/bin/runbit: line 107: exec: C:\Program: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the problem is that your JAVA_HOME is in directory with spaces (ex: Program Files).
To solve this you have two options:

1. Install JAVA in directory without spaces.
2. Replace "Program Files" in your JAVA_HOME variable to progra~1 or progra~2 (if in x86).

Example: 
JAVA_HOME="C:\progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_71"

Comment: apparently the error changed now  : ` Failure to connect to the zookeeper cluster service within the allotted time of 10000 milliseconds.
 at org.apache.drill.exec.coord.zk.ZKClusterCoordinator.start(ZKClusterCoordinator.java:123)` I will try to fix it, thanks

Comment: I launched Zookeeper and it works fine thanks a lot @Arina

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm if you were able to bring up Drill successfully on Windows - in embedded mode? That should be possible using the sqlline.bat file [1]. Regarding distributed mode (including single node), I don't think all the required batch scripts for configuring, launching and managing Drillbits on Windows are available.

You could give this a try - can take a look at existing linux shell scripts (under bin and conf directories) and create corresponding Windows equivalents. For any help, you could always reach out to the community via mailing lists [2].

[1] http://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-on-windows/

[2] http://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/

Comment: sqlline.bat runs successfully, all I want to do is to connect to the JDBC drivier in Windows ! There is a tutorial for using JDBC with SQuirreL in Windows but don't describe the way of running drillbit server thats why I got the error saying `there is no drillbit endpoint found from zookeeper` because drillbit is not running ! its the same error from SQuirrel and in my application !